# Как вывести весь список Chrome API history?

Tags: google-chrome, api, chrome-extension, extension, расширения

```
chrome.history.search({text: "", endTime: Date.now()}, function(c) {
})
```

Этот метод выводит список истории. В документации написано, что если `text` не указать, то должен выводиться весь список. Но он очень мал, в моем случае - это 53 записи.

Возможно ли вывести весь список? Тот, что можно увидеть в самой вкладке *История*.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации `chrome.history.search` возвращает историю для последнего посещения каждой страницы.

> Searches the history for the last visit time of each page matching the query.

Таким образом, если страница была посещена более одного раза, для нее будет возвращен только последний результат.

Попробуйте использовать это совместсно с методом [chrome.history.getVisits](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-getVisits), который возвращает информацию о всех посещениях для страницы с указаным URL.